# how to build a system such that this system should be able to represent any number using the vowels

Tags: encoding

Implement an encoding system to represent decimal numbers using only vowels a,e,i,o and u. In other words, this system should be able to represent any number using the vowels.

As part of the answer they should implement functions that take the encoding and decoding.

For example if `123` is encoded as `aei`, then the functions to be implemented are,

`encode(123) -> returns 'aei'`

`decode('aei') -> returns 123`

The encoding should be non-ambiguous and one-to-one, as in a given encoding can represent only a specific number.

I am a beginner in programming and stuck with this question. Any suggestion which algorithm is to used to solve the above problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution would be to express the number in [base-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinary) and then replace 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 with a, e, i, o, and u.